# Find uninitialized variables in C&C++

Tags: c++, c

I really mean C and C++. This project is using a lib in C which is calling my functions in C++. However the functions are in extern "C" because the lib expects it.

Anyways, in these functions I do `new Blah`. When a specific function is called (end_tree) i expect all my variables to be initialized. Using Visual Studios, GCC or any other compiler is there a way i can check? I just notice some bools are TRUE which shouldn't be... why, because it wasn't initialized. Is there some kind of `_VS_CheckThisMemory(mytree)` function or magic I can use?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know it this is what you want but `gcc` has `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` and `-Wuninitialized`. There may be more on [the warning options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: It doesnt help. My variables are all member vars and it should be checked after the obj ptr has been returned a few times.

Comment: @acidzombie: why don't you use initialize lists to not have that issue? Member variables are c++, so RAII should get you out of the mess you're in.

Comment: I don't think it will help in my specific case but can you show an example of what you mean? heres an example class http://codepad.org/RVCXChmq

Comment: @acidzombie24: have the default constructor setting those pointers to 0, or you'll soon be in trouble.

Comment: @Matthieu: Well the idea is i DONT set ANY default value because i MUST set ALL the values elsewhere. and i'd like something to check if i initialize the value or not and setting to default may confuse it. Most of the time i dont have all the info to set each value thus why i cant do it in the ctor

Comment: @acidzombie24: I understand, but with 0 you can test whether the pointer holds a dereferencable value or not (baring dead object addresses), while with garbage, you have no way to know it (at runtime). If you don't want to, fine, just don't expect me to ever work on your code.

Comment: @matthieu: ahhh hahahahahhaahahaha. If you seen this code, you'll understand why i cant change the structure. Its using C and i have NO TYPES whatesoever. Its looks a lot like functional programming. I build the middle of the structure and pass it back. Not only do i have to deal with lack of types and a nonlinear structure, i have more then 300 function and i cant make a struct for each and everyone of them. They also need serialization code. Its a difficult project!

Comment: @Matthieu i'd argue setting default values is as bad as uninitialized values. Why? Because the default values are meaningless and your program will run incorrectly. If there is a default value that has meaning (such as size 0 in an empty but initialize list) then it would make sense. However making the default time 12:00 makes no sense

Comment: @acidzombie24: I agree that default values make no sense, thus the idea of using an "invalid" value to represent the uninitialized state. If you expect the pointer to hold a value, then a null pointer is "invalid". If not, then you could cheat (using a 0xFFFFFFFFF value for example) etc... the point is to be able to diagnose at runtime whether or not it was uninitialized, and fail fast in case it is!

Comment: @Matthieu: Good idea. Original i decided to go throw the funcs&specs line by line making sure functions take all the params the specs specify and all the func use each param. But then i realize i have a few void* because the class isnt done and i may have forgotten to assign something which makes me need to go through it as least twice. Thus thus question and hoping theres an  already made tool that says i forgot to set a member in my class. However this is a good idea. I COULD make everything use a ptr which is null and either set a value or another ptr.

Answer (score 3):

Use valgrind (on linux)

```
./valgrind myprogram
```

Especially easy when myprogram was compiled with debug info (`gcc -g`), but not required. Valgrind will notify where memory is being used that was uninitialzed, and where it was allocated from. If it has debug info, valgrind will report exactly at which file:linenumber things happened. (*it can even attach a debugger on the fly for you to insepct things*)

It will also detect access beyond allocation boundaries and access after freeing. This is incredibly useful.

*Here endeth the useful answer*

---

**Edit** because it wasn't exactly clear why I was posting the following, as became clear from the comment, let me introduce the remainder of this answer:

When starting to use valgrind with existing codebases, it is almost inevitable that you'll get 'false' positives, i.e. reports that aren't really problems (yet). I include *one* example of what might trigger such a report, and how you'd *typically* fix those.

**I'm just including this to raise awareness of how to tackle or recognize (semi-)false positives.**

*Another way of wording it (with reference to Matthieu's convincing reasoning in the comments) is to treat even the 'not-actually-killing' Valgrind warnings as critical: get them fixed, not forgotten*.

It *is possible* that valgrind will report uninitialized access when it is not really a problem. Like, e.g.

```
 char buf[1024];
 strcpy(buf, "hello");

 char clone[1024];
 memcpy(clone, buf, 1024);
```

You *should* fix that by doing something smarter like

```
 memcpy(clone, buf, strlen(buf));
```

To make sure there are no uninitialzed 'parts' in buf (or at least not in the area accessed)

Comment: @sehe: I would consider bad design to copy more than what you set in the buffer anyway. It's not only a waste of time, it also mean that you're copying leftover from another run, and who knows what havoc it'll bring...

Comment: @Matthieu: instead of complaining how much it hurts to be accused of giving bad advice, I decided I clarified the answer and made it abundantly clear why I mention false positives. I'm still including the info, because it is usually the first question/reason for a rejection with valgrind.

Comment: General notice: valgrind has a mechanism to configure ignores in your own codebase. You might want to use that when your project gets married to valgrind 100%.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Also, reading back on your comment `"and who knows what havoc it'll bring..."` -- this is of course FUD (especially since the alternative was allowing uninitialized data, which is analytically equivalent to having leftover data there)

Comment: @sehe: not so FUD, here you used `strcpy`, so the string is 0-terminated, however if you had used `memcpy` there (as in the second call) and "messed up" the size (the infamous off by one error), then you have a non-terminated string followed by garbage. It is much more desirable to know which portion of the buffer is used in the first place. Now, I do recognize that valgrind may emit false positives, but for uninitialized values, I had expected the infamous Debian example: http://research.swtch.com/2008/05/lessons-from-debianopenssl-fiasco.html

Comment: @Matthieu: Ah, I see where you're coming from now. Of course, that doesn't apply to this trivial example, but I do agree that there is superior way to get rid of the valgrind warning here (I had been reading your comment the other way around earlier). I'll in fact go and adapt the answer, because, although it is not risky in the dumb example, the fact that even (anal-retentive) Debian devs get it wrong when glossing over the mechanics of their own code... it's much better to err on the explicit side (not necessarily safe, but 'in-your-face'). Your example is now famous with me too. Thanks!

Comment: @sehe: actually, the Debian dev get the warning wrong. They sought to get rid of it, while using unitialized memory was a way for OpenSSL to gather more entropy :) Of course, a comment underlining why it was unitialized in the first place would have cleared any doubt... But in every day code, it's better to fix them (like compiler warnings, in fact) than disabling them (either by flags, pragmas or suppression files) unless there is a real reason for doing things this way (like using overflow as part of a hashing method) in which case it should be clearly documented right next to the code.

Comment: @sehe: now I just cannot think of a valid reason to raise a warning in valgrind (wrt uninitialized) off the top of my hat (other than OpenSSL trick). It would have been easier if the OP had asked about memory leaks :D

Answer (score 2):

Use a self-initializing class to cover those annoying primitives.

```
template<typename T> class always_initialized {
    T t;
public:
    always_initialized()
        : t(T()) {}
    always_initialized(const T& ref) {
        : t(ref) {}
    operator T&() { return t; }
    operator const T&() const { return t; }
    T& operator=(const T& ref) { return t = ref; }
};
```

Comment: Nice! I have often wished that some compiler would implement a flag to initialize them unconditionally :/ I am afraid this rule brought more havoc than it saved cycles.

Comment: +1. Maybe also add a function like this to allow it to work with pointers: inline typename std::remove_pointer< T >::type* operator->() const { return t; }

Answer (score 2):

In response to the code linked in the comment, RAIIIA (`Resource Acquisition is Initialization In Action (R)`)

```
class OtherClass;
class MyClass : public SomeBase {
public:
    // note I got rid of your default constructor, which leaves values unitialized
    MyClass(Var* name, OtherClass* loop)
    :   m_name(name), m_loop(loop) // this right here
    {   }
    virtual ~MyClass(); // no implementation needed here

    void save();

    // made the members protected, other classes have no business accessing them directly
protected:
    Var* m_name;
    OtherClass* m_loop;
};
```

Your default constructor left the values unitialized, and goes against RAII in its pure form. It's OK to do that, but as you're having problems with uninitialized variables, I would recomment removing default constructors.

EDIT: storing unknown pointers as class members without `new`ing and `delete`ing them in the class constructor/destructor isn't really RAII, but I hope you do that somewhere.

Comment: ohh so this is what you meant. +1. However in my case i don't have enough info to set the constructor. I'm considering going through this chart line by line and make sure everything is initalized

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a solution with templates to act like properties. I used [Property like features in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079052/property-like-features-in-c/6080497#6080497) but there are other examples for other things like passing in a get/setter.

Essentially generated most of this code bc i was able to and i kept track if a variable was set or not through the property. At the end i just check members and had asserts to tell me if i set a variable or not. I also assert when i 'get' just in case.