# Property like features in C++?

Tags: c++

My use is pretty complicated. I have a bunch of objs and they are all passed around by ptr (not reference or value unless its an enum which is byval). At a specific point in time i like to call CheckMembers() which will check if each member has been set or is null. By default i cant make it all null because i wouldnt know if i set it to null or if it is still null bc i havent touch it since the ctor.

To assign a variable i still need the syntax to be the normal `var = p; var->member = new Type;`. I generate all the classes/members. So my question is how can i implement a property like feature where i can detect if the value has been set or left as the default?

I am thinking maybe i can use C++ with CLR/.NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z974bes2.aspx but i never used it before and have no idea how well it will work and what might break in my C++ prj (it uses rtti, templates, etc).

Comment: Have you considered using words like "because" rather than "bc", or "project" rather than "prj"? Or are you submitting your questions via a mobile phone?

Comment: @Seth, have you considered editing the question to fix them if it bothers you that badly?

Comment: [The N1615 paper has a library solution for implementing properties](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1615.pdf). I'm not sure how well it meets your requirements, but implementing a property-like feature in C++ is definitely possible. At least the N1615 document can give you some hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reality (edit): this proved to be tricky, but the following code should handle your requirements. It uses a simple counter in the base class. The counter is incremented once for every property you wish to track, and then decremented once for every property that is set. The `checkMembers()` function only has to verify that the counter is equal to zero. As a bonus, you could potentially report *how many* members were not initialized.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PropertyBase
{
    public:
        int * counter;
        bool is_set;
};

template <typename T>
class Property : public PropertyBase
{
    public:
        T* ptr;
        T* operator=(T* src)
        {
            ptr = src;
            if (!is_set) { (*counter)--; is_set = true; }
            return ptr;
        }
        T* operator->() { return ptr; }
        ~Property() { delete ptr; }
};

class Base
{
    private:
        int counter;
    protected:
        void TrackProperty(PropertyBase& p)
        {
            p.counter = &counter;
            counter++;
        }
    public:
        bool checkMembers() { return (counter == 0); }
};

class OtherObject : public Base { }; // just as an example

class MyObject : public Base
{
    public:
        Property<OtherObject> x;
        Property<OtherObject> y;
        MyObject();
};

MyObject::MyObject()
{
    TrackProperty(x);
    TrackProperty(y);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MyObject * object1 = new MyObject();
    MyObject * object2 = new MyObject();

    object1->x = new OtherObject();
    object1->y = new OtherObject();

    cout << object1->checkMembers() << endl; // true
    cout << object2->checkMembers() << endl; // false

    delete object1;
    delete object2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that. A bit more info, all objs are pass by ptr. So i'm sure `func(T*p) { p->...` would not call the overload since its a ptr and not a ref/val obj? However can i overload `p->thisobj = val` in some way? +1 btw

Comment: @acidzombie24: The code that I posted should work even through function calls. Each `Property<T>` member is really just a smart pointer with a bit of counting logic added in

Comment: One more added bonus: you can check each member's status: `if (object1->x.is_set) ...`

Comment: I'm looking through the code now. The first thing i notice was `if (ptr != NULL) { delete ptr; }` Its allowed to call delete ptr while its null so that check is useless ;)

Comment: Learn something every day `:)`

Comment: You also didnt initialize the counter. I notice it failed when i first ran it but now i see why. Actually, i'll paste the modified code. -edit- when i am done

Comment: Shouldn't need to. Doesn't the standard guarantee that members are set to zero? Same goes for `is_set`

Comment: @me: Hmmm. no, it doesn't. Well, apparently you learn *two* things in one day. I've been coding in Objective-C for too long!

Comment: A big wtf i had was when i was told i dont need a return value for main and it is always 0 if none is specified. -edit- i would have this done but i cant remember how to overload *, the ptr kind, not multiplication.

Comment: How silly of me. I knew exactly how to do it. I took a break and remembered. I posted my own answer below and i'll leave none accepted since i used both answer solutions

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways to do this, with varying tradeoffs in terms of space overhead. For example, here's one option:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename OuterClass>
class Property
{
public:
    typedef void (OuterClass::*setter)(const T &value);
    typedef T &value_type;
    typedef const T &const_type;
private:
    setter set_;
    T &ref_;
    OuterClass *parent_;
public:
    operator value_type() { return ref_; }
    operator const_type() const { return ref_; }

    Property<T, OuterClass> &operator=(const T &value)
    {
        (parent_->*set_)(value);
        return *this;
    }

    Property(T &ref, OuterClass *parent, setter setfunc)
        : set_(setfunc), ref_(ref), parent_(parent)
    { }
};


struct demo {
    private:
        int val_p;
        void set_val(const int &newval) {
            std::cout << "New value: " << newval << std::endl;
            val_p = newval;
        }

    public:
        Property<int, demo> val;

        demo()
            : val(val_p, this, &demo::set_val)
        { }
};

int main() {
    demo d;
    d.val = 42;
    std::cout << "Value is: " << d.val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's possible to get less overhead (this has up to `4 * sizeof(void*)` bytes overhead) using template accessors - here's another example:

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T, typename ParentType, typename AccessTraits>
class Property
{
private:
    ParentType *get_parent()
    {
        return (ParentType *)((char *)this - AccessTraits::get_offset());
    }
public:
    operator T &() { return AccessTraits::get(get_parent()); }
    operator T() { return AccessTraits::get(get_parent()); }
    operator const T &() { return AccessTraits::get(get_parent()); }
    Property &operator =(const T &value) {
        AccessTraits::set(get_parent(), value);
        return *this;
    }
};

#define DECL_PROPERTY(ClassName, ValueType, MemberName, TraitsName) \
    struct MemberName##__Detail : public TraitsName { \
        static ptrdiff_t get_offset() { return offsetof(ClassName, MemberName); }; \
    }; \
    Property<ValueType, ClassName, MemberName##__Detail> MemberName;

struct demo {
    private:
        int val_;

        struct AccessTraits {
            static int get(demo *parent) {
                return parent->val_;
            }

            static void set(demo *parent, int newval) {
                std::cout << "New value: " << newval << std::endl;
                parent->val_ = newval;
            }
        };
    public:
        DECL_PROPERTY(demo, int, val, AccessTraits)

        demo()
        { val_ = 0; }
};

int main() {
    demo d;
    d.val = 42;
    std::cout << "Value is: " << (int)d.val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This only consumes one byte for the property struct itself; however, it relies on unportable `offsetof()` behavior (you're not technically allowed to use it on non-POD structures). For a more portable approach, you could stash just the `this` pointer of the parent class in a member variable.

Note that both classes are just barely enough to demonstrate the technique - you'll want to overload `operator*` and `operator->`, etc, as well.

Comment: i'm still reading the code but i dont need less overhead. I can just toggle the generation with a switch and only use this in debug.

Comment: Excellent. I think this will work just fine. I'll try it within 24hrs :)

Comment: I added my own light weight version as an answer. I wont mark any solution as correct. I notice you did the more complex property where you can set you own getter/setter. Nice touch (my doesnt support that)

Comment: Yes, it's easier to implement if you let the property class contain the backing value - but I enjoyed the challenge :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my temporary alternative. One that doesn't ask for constructor parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Property
{
    bool isSet;
    T v;
    Property(Property&p) { }
public:
    Property() { isSet=0; }
    T operator=(T src) { v = src; isSet = 1; return v; }
    operator T() const { assert(isSet); return v; }
    bool is_set() { return isSet; }
};

class SomeType  {};
enum  SomeType2 { none, a, b};
class MyObject
{
public:
    Property<SomeType*> x;
    Property<SomeType2> y;
    //This should be generated. //Consider generating ((T)x)->checkMembers() when type is a pointer
    bool checkMembers() { return x.is_set() && y.is_set(); }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    MyObject* p = new MyObject();
    p->x = new SomeType;
    cout << p->checkMembers() << endl; // false
    p->y = a;
    cout << p->checkMembers() << endl; // true
    delete p->x;
    delete p;
}
```