# Why is the dtor being called (using annoymous/lambda func)

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, destructor, c++11

I am trying to mimic a finally like effect. So i thought i should run a quick dirty test.

The idea was to use [Most Important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) to stop destruction and to put the finally block in a lambda. However apparently i did something wrong and its being called at the end of MyFinally(). How do i solve this problem?

```
#include <cassert>
template<typename T>
class D{
    T fn;
public:
    D(T v):fn(v){}
    ~D(){fn();}
};

template<typename T>
const D<T>& MyFinally(T t) { return D<T>(t); }

int d;
class A{
    int a;
public:
    void start(){
        int a=1;
        auto v = MyFinally([&]{a=2;});
        try{
            assert(a==1);
            //do stuff
        }
        catch(int){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;
    a.start();
}
```

My Solution code (Note: You can not have two finally in the same block. as expect. But still kind of dirty)

```
#include <cassert>
template<typename T>
class D{
    T fn; bool exec;
public:
    D(T v):fn(v),exec(true){}
    //D(D const&)=delete //VS doesnt support this yet and i didnt feel like writing virtual=0
    D(D &&d):fn(move(d.fn)), exec(d.exec) {
      d.exec = false;
    }

    ~D(){if(exec) fn();}
};
template<typename T>
D<T> MyFinally(T t) { return D<T>(t); }


#define FINALLY(v) auto OnlyOneFinallyPlz = MyFinally(v)

int d;
class A{
public:
    int a;
    void start(){
        a=1;
        //auto v = MyFinally([&]{a=2;});
        FINALLY([&]{a=2;});
        try{
            assert(a==1);
            //do stuff
        }
        catch(int){
            FINALLY([&]{a=3;}); //ok, inside another scope
            try{
                assert(a==1);
                //do other stuff
            }
            catch(int){
                //do other stuff
            }
        }
    }
};
void main() {
    A a;
    a.start();
    assert(a.a==2);
}
```

Funny enough, if you remove the & in MyFinally in the original code it works -_-.

Comment: nice thought! You could also call this `defer` (like in Go), although it's never clear until when it is deferred...

Comment: Join this topic : [Simulating finally block in C++0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167515/simulating-finally-block-in-c0xx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// WRONG! returning a reference to a temporary that will be
// destroyed at the end of the function!
template<typename T>
const D<T>& MyFinally(T t) { return D<T>(t); }
```

You can fix it my introducing a move constructor

```
template<typename T>
class D{
    T fn;
    bool exec;

public:
    D(T v):fn(move(v)),exec(true){}

    D(D &&d):fn(move(d.fn)), exec(d.exec) {
      d.exec = false;
    }

    ~D(){if(exec) fn();}
};
```

And then you can rewrite your toy

```
template<typename T>
D<T> MyFinally(T t) { return D<T>(move(t)); }
```

Hope it helps. No "const reference" trick is needed when you work with `auto`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419650/c-c-macro-template-blackmagic-to-generate-unique-name/2419715#2419715) for how to do it in C++03 with const references.

Comment: I've one doubt : `move` in `return D<T>(move(t));` is necessary? Why exactly?.... and in *D(T v): **fn(move(v))** ,exec(true){}*?

Comment: @Nawaz because those are not among the cases where a move is done automatically.

Comment: In my solution, I'm using `pointer-to-base`; I just don't like it; I want to use reference instead. So can I use `move` to accomplish that? I'm trying, but not able to do that; never worked with `std::move` before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167515/simulating-finally-block-in-c0x

Answer (score 2):

Your code and Sutter's are not equivalent. His function returns a value, yours returns a reference to an object that will be destroyed when the function exits. The const reference in the calling code does not maintain the lifetime of that object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from the use of a function maker, as demonstrated by Johannes.

I would argue that you could avoid the issue by using another C++0x facility, namely `std::function`.

```
class Defer
{
public:
  typedef std::function<void()> Executor;

  Defer(): _executor(DoNothing) {}

  Defer(Executor e): _executor(e) {}
  ~Defer() { _executor(); }

  Defer(Defer&& rhs): _executor(rhs._executor) {
    rhs._executor = DoNothing;
  }

  Defer& operator=(Defer rhs) {
    std::swap(_executor, rhs._executor);
    return *this;
  }

  Defer(Defer const&) = delete;

private:
  static void DoNothing() {}
  Executor _executor;
};
```

Then, you can use it as simply:

```
void A::start() {
  a = 1;
  Defer const defer([&]() { a = 2; });

  try { assert(a == 1); /**/ } catch(...) { /**/ }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `&` in `[]() { a = 2; }`. It should be `[&]() { a = 2; }`

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks for the catch... I am not used to those lambdas yet :/

Comment: wow, i dont need the auto keyword for this solution. I like it!

Comment: @acidzombie24: the cheat is that `auto` is somewhat contained in `std::function`, since it can take both function pointers (or references) and lambdas :) I have added move semantics so that it may be returned from a function, if you so wish.

Comment: @Matthieu: See my second solution and let me know what you think.

Comment: btw do you remember this conversation where i didnt want to use default values set in the ctor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921439/find-uninitialized-variables-in-cc/5921469#5921469 i solved it by using this in which i generated the classes including the checkMembers function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079052/property-like-features-in-c/6080497#6080497

Comment: @Nawaz: checked, as well as the subsequent question, I still find using `std::function` neater.

Comment: @Matthieu: But that is not generic solution. If I'm not wrong, object of type `std::function<void()>` can hold address of function type `void (*)()` only , right?

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is explained by others, so I will suggest a fix, exactly in the same way Herb Sutter has written his code (your code is not same as his, by the way):

First, don't return by const reference:

```
template<typename T>
D<T> MyFinally(T t) 
{
   D<T> local(t); //create a local variable
   return local; 
}
```

Then write this at call site:

```
const auto & v = MyFinally([&]{a=2;}); //store by const reference
```

This became exactly like Herb Sutter's [code](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/uSkhP

Now the destructor is called just before exiting the `start()` function.

---

### A different implementation which doesn't use auto keyword anymore:

```
struct base { virtual ~base(){} };

template<typename TLambda>
struct exec : base 
{
   TLambda lambda;
   exec(TLambda l) : lambda(l){}
   ~exec() { lambda(); }
};

class lambda{
    base *pbase;
public:
    template<typename TLambda>
    lambda(TLambda l): pbase(new exec<TLambda>(l)){}
    ~lambda() { delete pbase; }
};
```

And use it as:

```
lambda finally = [&]{a=2;  std::cout << "finally executed" << std::endl; };
```

Looks interesting?

Complete demo : http://www.ideone.com/DYqrh

Comment: This won't work if the impl doesn't elide the temporary. It would execute the dtor of the temporary in the return statement.

Comment: @Johannes: actually it does work. Its basically my code except MyFinally returns `D<T>` instead of `D<T>&`. I tested it in VS2010

Comment: @acid I think you haven't understood my comment. Your compiler optimizes away the temporary and (in @Nawaz changed answer) the local variable.

Comment: @Johannes: ohh, i missed the 'if'. Btw i got that c++03 trick to work. Nawaz: He is saying IF the compiler implementation calls the dtor twice (once for the temporary, once after it returns) this wont work.

Comment: @acidzombie24 and @Johannes : See my second solution. Let me know your opinion.

Comment: I'm sorry it has the same problem. It can crash if the compiler doesn't elide the temporary in the copy initialization, because then it deletes twice with the same pointer value.

Comment: @Johannes: How exactly? How can `~lambda()` be called twice?

Comment: @Nawaz this will be too much to explain in a comment. If you want to know what happens exactly, I recommend to open a new question.

Comment: @Johannes: Actually the standard should be checked. They might specify if the variable should elide or not. Also do either of you know if virtual is REQUIRED by this trick? in my current code i literally use struct Dummy{} (and it seems fine)

Comment: @Johannes: Done. Please join it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167515/simulating-finally-block-in-c0x

Answer (score 0):

You could return a shared_ptr:

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<D<T>> MyFinally(T t) {
    return std::shared_ptr<D<T>>(new D<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it is really less efficient :/

Comment: @Matthieu: Compared to what?  And why?

Comment: compared to the original solution. You allocate memory on the free store (which is never cheap) and you use `shared_ptr` which involves counter updates that are synchronized for multi-threading situations and thus involve broadcasting updates among cores to make sure the processors' cache are in sync.