# Simulating finally block in C++0x

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, try-catch, finally

Inspired from [the other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167017/why-is-the-dtor-being-called-using-annoymous-lambda-func), I wrote this code which simulates a `finally` block:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct base { virtual ~base(){} };

template<typename TLambda>
struct exec : base 
{
   TLambda lambda;
   exec(TLambda l) : lambda(l){}
   ~exec() { lambda(); }
};

class lambda{
    base *pbase;
public:
    template<typename TLambda>
    lambda(TLambda l): pbase(new exec<TLambda>(l)){}
    ~lambda() { delete pbase; }
};

class A{
    int a;
public:
    void start(){
        int a=1;        
        lambda finally = [&]{a=2; std::cout<<"finally executed";}; 
        try{
            assert(a==1);
            //do stuff
        }
        catch(int){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;
    a.start();
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/WAL7d)):

```
finally executed
```

@Johannes seems to think that its not entirely correct, and [commented that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167017/why-is-the-dtor-being-called-using-annoymous-lambda-func/6167089#6167089):

> It can crash if the compiler doesn't
>   elide the temporary in the copy
>   initialization, because then it
>   deletes twice with the same pointer
>   value

I would like to know how exactly. Help me understanding the problem :-)

---

EDIT:

Problem fixed as:

```
class lambda{
    base *pbase;
public:
    template<typename TLambda>
    lambda(TLambda l): pbase(new exec<TLambda>(l)){}
    ~lambda() { delete pbase; }

    lambda(const lambda&)= delete;            //disable copy ctor
    lambda& operator=(const lambda&)= delete; //disable copy assignment
};
```

And then use it as:

```
//direct initialization, no copy-initialization
lambda finally([&]{a=2;  std::cout << "finally executed" << std::endl; });
```

Complete code : http://www.ideone.com/hsX0X

Comment: What a waste of heap allocation.

Comment: @DeadMG: Actually I was trying to do that with reference, but it didn't work, and I didn't try it again. :|

Comment: @Nawaz: Why not just store it as the object it is? `const auto&` will do it just fine.

Comment: @DeadMG: I tried that. But the lamdba is executed!

Comment: Beware that this doesn't really act like `finally`, if the user puts code between the try block and the function exit, then the lambda executes after that other code. Also, if ScopeGuard (http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403758) doesn't work with a lambda, then it should be prodded until it does :-)

Comment: @Steve: Yeah. Its a different kind of finally which will be executed no matter what, even if there is no `try-catch`. Its suitable for cases when some invariant checking is done before exiting the function, more like Aspect Oriented Programmming, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: shameless plug: a C++0xified version of Marginean's scope guard can be seen here: http://pizer.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/scope-guards-revisited-c0x-style/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this initialization:

```
lambda finally = [&]{a=2; std::cout<<"finally executed";};
```

The implicitly defined copy constructor for `lambda` may be used. This will just copy the raw pointer `pbase` which will then be deleted more than once.

E.g.

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors lambdafun.cc 
$ ./a.out 
a.out: lambdafun.cc:29: void A::start(): Assertion `a==1' failed.
finally executedAborted (core dumped)
```

Actually, your assert firing masks the double delete problem, but this demonstrates the crash I was highlighting.

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors -DNDEBUG lambdafun.cc 
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Yes, you might want to forbid copying of your class `lambda` to be safe as copying a `lambda` clearly isn't safe.

Comment: @Nawaz: `lambda(const lambda&) = delete;` and similar.

Comment: @Charles: Wow.. my first use of `=delete`.

Comment: And also.. `lambda& operator=(const lambda&)= delete;`

Answer (score 2):

Seems way more complicated than necessary.  Why not just:

```
class finally
{
    std::function<void (void)> const action;
    finally(const finally&) = delete;

public:
    finally(std::function<void (void)> a)
        : action(a)
    {}

    ~finally() { action(); }
};
```

But in general, one should try not to carry bad Java habits over into C++.

Comment: That is for specific lambda of type `void (*)()`? Can it work with lamda or function of signature `void (*)(int,int)`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Where are the arguments going to come from?  The number and type of arguments supplied when the destructor calls the lambda determine the required signature.  Your code `~exec() { lambda(); }` permits no arguments.  If the lambda needs more data, it needs to capture it.